# Where can I purchase a replacement screw for my MacBook Pro SuperDrive?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive, hardware

While replacing the logic board on my MacBook Pro (15" 2.4 GHz) and I stripped one of the 3.3mm 00 Phillips screws for the SuperDrive.  I have found only one source online that had replacements in stock (http://www.impactcomputers.com/), and they wanted to charge me $19.99 + shipping for 5 of them.  Are stores like this my only recourse, or does anyone know of a better online distributer of Mac parts?

I have checked ifixit.com and I would like to avoid buying full $60 sets for one replacement.

Comment: Go to the apple store. If it's just 1 screw and your fairly polite, they'll get it to you from their back room just to get you out of the already crowded store :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store) is a good place for parts. They seem to sell complete screw kits for different models.

Although one screw missing won’t hurt the unit. I repaired a machine recently that is literally held together with celo tape and stickers.

Comment: Yes bet he wants to avoid spending $60 for a single screw, as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ebay? [ebay search for "macbook pro screws"](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=macbook%20pro%20screws&_sacat=0&_odkw=3.3mm%20screws%20macbook%20pro&_osacat=0&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313)

Comment: I was only able to locate full screw sets, so that was no dice.  Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any old dead computers, or know someone who does? They provide a cheap and ready source of ridiculously expensive to replace parts, including such things as small metric screws.

Comment: A great idea!  But sadly I couldn't find anyone with this model, I ended up just leaving the screw out...no harm it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/). They sell Mac parts and kits so they might be able to help you. I have used them in the past and they so far no complaints.